# How to avoid using transpose when putting values from array to column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting data in a collection from a web request and I need to put it into a column. While this function does what it needs, it is slow. I have already set xlCalculationManual in an earlier function and ScreenUpdating and EnableEvents did not affect much.

I need to run the data inserts in batches of 15000 because transpose returns only about 17900 first items. But could I build the array in CollectionToArray function in such a way that I don't need to transpose it? I tried to make it return a two dimensional array and put the values to the second dimension, but it did not work. I still needed to transpose it, or all the rows in the column had the first element of the array.

```
Function replaceList(startCol As Integer, endCol As Integer, values As Collection)
    Dim batch As Long
    Dim batchStart As Long
    Dim batchEnd As Long
    Dim b As Long
    
    batch = 15000
    With Worksheets("MyData")
        Do While b * batch < values.Count
            If (b + 1) * batch > values.Count Then
                batchEnd = values.Count
            Else
                batchEnd = (b + 1) * batch
            End If
            batchStart = b * batch + 1
            .Range(.Cells(batchStart + 2, startCol), .Cells(batchEnd + 2, endCol)).Value = Application.Transpose(CollectionToArray(values, batchStart, batchEnd))
            b = b + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Function

Function CollectionToArray(C As Collection, batchStart As Long, batchEnd As Long) As Variant()
    Dim a() As Variant: ReDim a(0 To (batchEnd - batchStart))
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    
    j = 0
    For i = batchStart To batchEnd
        a(j) = C.item(i)
        j = j + 1
    Next
    CollectionToArray = a
End Function
```

Comment: when using a 2D array you would put the values in the first dimension not the second.  A 1D array is horizontal.  A 2D array the first dimension is the vertical dimension and the second is the horizontal.  If you load an array that is `arr(1 to 15000, 1 to 1)` there will be no reason to transpose.

Comment: Oh my! I was not able to even think that it would take the vertical from the first dimension when 1D is horizontal. Thanks!

Comment: So in your case: `ReDim a(1 To (batchEnd - batchStart +1),1 to 1)` then `a(j,1) = C.item(i)` and start j at `1`

Answer (score 0):

### Write Collection Values to a Worksheet Column

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the numbers from one to a million to a collection
'               and returns the values of the collection in a one-column range.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Calls:        'WriteCollectionToColumnRange'
'                   'GetCollection'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub CollectionToColumnExample()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("MyData")
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range("A2")
    
    ' Populate collection with dummy data.
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 1000000
        coll.Add n
    Next n
    
    ' Write the values to a range.
    WriteCollectionToColumnRange fCell, coll
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a collection in a one-column range.
' Calls:        'GetCollection'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub WriteCollectionToColumnRange( _
        ByVal FirstCell As Range, _
        ByVal coll As Object)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetCollection(coll)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = FirstCell.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), 1)
    rg.Value = Data
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Returns the values from a collection in a 2D one-based one-column array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetCollection( _
    ByVal coll As Collection) _
As Variant
    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To coll.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For Each Item In coll
        r = r + 1
        Data(r, 1) = Item
    Next Item
    
    GetCollection = Data
    
End Function
```